# Suma de NULL problema con resultado, si el valor del dato es nulo

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Necesito traer la suma de 2 datos:

```
dato1 = 1
dato2 = 2
totalsuma = 3
```

Actualmente lo hago así:

```
 SET  totalsuma = (SELECT SUM(dato1+dato2) from tabla WHERE  CODIGO  = codigo_new);
```

hasta alli todo bien la variable totalsuma me toma el valor 3,
el problema lo tengo cuando unos de los datos tiene valor nulo, ej:

```
dato1 = 1
dato2 = null
totalsuma = null
```

Cuando tengo unos de los datos en `null`, simplemente no se realiza la tarea esperada.

Alguien me podrá ayudar en mi *procedimiento almacenado*, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, indica qué manejador de base de datos estás usando. Al no ponerlo, aparecen respuestas a tu pregunta de todo tipo, muchas de las cuales podrían llevar a confusión o al uso de funciones suplementarias innecesarias que podrían tener un impacto más o menos grande en la optimización/rendimiento de la consulta.

Comment: Disculpa, lo olvide, estoy utilizando MySql

Comment: Entonces es como te han dicho, usando `IFNULL`... también puedes usar `COALESCE`. Ten en cuenta que si usas `SUM` te agrupará todos los registros con la condición del `WHERE`.

Comment: Gracias A.Cedano si es lo que necesito ;) tambien podrias indicar la funcion de COALESCE  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta utilizar la función [ifnull](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

```
SET totalsuma = (SELECT SUM(ifnull( dato1, 0 ) + ifnull(dato2,0)) 
                from tabla 
                WHERE CODIGO = codigo_new);
```

Comment: lo pruebo ahora y te comento!

Comment: Muchas gracias, es la función que necesitaba ;)

Answer (score 2):

Soluciones posibles:
 
 
**MySQL**

La funcion de MySQL IFNULL() regresa un valor en caso de que la expresion sea nula: `IFNULL(dato,0)`

**SQL Server**

la función de SQL SERVER ISNULL() también te permite retornar un valor alternativo en caso de que la variable sea nula: 
 `ISNULL(dato,0)`

**Oracle**

La función de ORACLE NVL() nos da el mismo resultado que las anteriores: 
 `NVL(dato, 0)`

En tu caso especifico necesitarías hacer algo como esto:

```
SET  totalsuma = (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(dato1,0)+ISNULL(dato2,0)) 
from tabla WHERE  CODIGO  = codigo_new);
```

Comment: Este sitio es en castellano, no sé por qué la respuesta está en inglés. Además para ciertos manejadores de Base de datos no aplica aplicar la función que además puede ser muy costosa, como es el caso de `ISNULL`. Antes de responder es mejor que el OP indique qué manejador de BD está usando, para dar una respuesta basada en ese manejador.

Comment: Una disculpa pensé que estaba en el sitio en Ingles, tienes razon pero solo en ciertos casos la funcion `ISNULL` es costosa de utilizar como el caso de escribirla en el `WHERE`. Lo mejor sería que nos especificara que manejador de BD esta utilizando. Te dejo un enlace [Using is null in where clause is expensive](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/using-isnull-in-where-clause-is-expensive)

Comment: El hecho es que por ejemplo den SQL Server, el uso de `SUM` sobre un conjunto de valores donde uno de ellos sean `NULL` el resultado no se ve afectado. Por tanto, el uso de `ISNULL` en ese caso es innecesario, no sirve para nada más que para sobrecargar el código. Y lo del rendimiento puede ser muy costoso, si se manejan muchos datos (la consulta podría estar agrupando miles... millones de filas).

Comment: Estimados, actualmente utilizo MySql, probare ahora y comento.

Comment: gracias por especificar la función para distintos motores, definitivamente la de MySql es la que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar, también se podría hacer con **[`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)**, tal y como se hace con `IFNULL`.

`COALESCE` forma parte del standard TSQL.

```
SET totalsuma = (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(dato1, 0) + COALESCE(dato2,0)) 
                from tabla 
                WHERE CODIGO = codigo_new);
```